# Getting a Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Getting error when invoking this method. Need two properties firstName and lastName

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetEmployees(string lifeNumber)
{
    PCF.Entities.Data.Entities db = new PCF.Entities.Data.Entities();
    var data = db.MasterTables
                 .Where(x => x.Life_Hosp == lifeNumber)
                 .Select(x => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName });
    return data.ToList();
}
```

Comment: What about the error don't you understand?  It seems pretty self explanatory.

Comment: I am trying to get FirstName and LastName but it seems i have the wrong return type

Comment: @user2224493 Indeed.  So you do understand the problem.  So what's your question for us?  You apparently already know what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` is a list of an anonymous type with two properties one the `FirstName` and the other the `LastName`. Your method's return type is a list of strings. Apparently, there is a difference between the return type of your method and the thign your return.

There are two options.

The first is to change the method's return type and change the type you return from your method's body.

The second is to change that you return from your method body to a string.

Since Moo-Juice has already shown you the latter option, I will try to show you the first option.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees(string lifeNumber)
{
    PCF.Entities.Data.Entities db = new PCF.Entities.Data.Entities();
    var data = db.MasterTables
                .Where(x => x.Life_Hosp == lifeNumber)
                .Select(x => new Employee
                 {
                     FirstName = x.FirstName, 
                     LastName = x.LastName 
                 });
    return data.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Servy mentions in the comments, this is pretty self explanatory.

`data` is going to be a collection of first names and last names.  Which a `List<string>` most definitely is not.

You might want to try something along the lines of:

```
var data = db.MasterTables
                .Where(x => x.Life_Hosp == lifeNumber)
                .Select(x => string.Concat(x.FirstName, " ", x.LastName));
```

The result of which, is a string - which is what you want.  Now, given the comment just made, you could do something else:

```
public sealed class Name 
{ 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
} // eo class Name
```

And then your query is:

```
var data = db.MasterTables
                .Where(x => x.Life_Hosp == lifeNumber)
                .Select(x => new Name() { FirstName = = x.FirstName, LastName = y.LastName });
```

But obviously you'd have to change the return value of your method:

Comment: But he says, "Need two properties firstName and lastName", implying that a concatted string isn't an option.

Comment: @Servy though also, to be fair, as the question states he wants both properties - but not how they are consumed.  I'll leave that up to others as the question is rather unclear ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments very helpful. Which option is better when using an ajax call to get this data